# Problem with styling python-docx-template

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to create a .docx document, where in template.docx I have

```
{{r rt }}
```

and in python code

```
concat = RichText('A   ', bold=False)
concat.add("B", bold=False)
job.context['rt'] = concat
```

Somehow I get both A und B in bold. If I try template as

```
{{rt}}
```

then just the first element A is normal and all other (B and next) are bold.
It looks like RichText generates the right xml data

```
<w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">A   </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">B</w:t></w:r>
```

That means the problem should be in MS Word (version 2011), but I have no idea, why...